# How can I insert Billing Information after Providing Patient Diagnosis Information in one-to-one relationship One after another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, one-to-one

The Application I am trying to make is Hospital Management System. In the EnterPatientDiagnosis Form(screenshot is given at the end), I need to Add The Patient's Diagnosis Information 1st then I need to Add its associated Billing Information. Here,Both of tables Primary Key Column is an Identity Column.
This is a common step in many Systems .But I still couldn't find details on how to achieve it.

One solution I thought of is to insert all the Diagnosis Information keeping the FK_billId attribute Null using Stored Procedure and get the DiagnosisId as output parameter form the Stored Procedure. Then when user will Submit Bill information I will use the BillId and DiagnosisId to update the previously inserted row in the Diagnosis Table. But I do not like this approach for 2 reason:

**Firstly**, *Because it has an extra update query.* Since, If I used the DiagnosisId as a foreign key between this 2 Database Tables rather than BillId then there would not be any need for this update query. But I haven't found anywhere giving any rules/precedence on which Key you should use as FK in One-to-One relation.

**Secondly**, *It conflicts with the Entity Class that I have created.* I have manually created 2 classes for this 2 tables in my Entity Layer. So, If I want to insert row through entity layer then I would have to give The Billing class a new Property named DiagnosisId which is contradictory with my Database Table Schema.
Here is the 2 classes in Entity Layer:

```
public class EntityPatientDiagnosis
{
    //Diagnosis Id is automatically assigned   
    public int DiagnosisId { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }


    public string Symptoms { get; set; }
    public string DiagnosisProvided { get; set;}

    public string AdministeredBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateofDiagnosis { get; set; }
    public string FollowUpRequired { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfFollowUp { get; set; }
    public int BillId { get; set; } //BillId -> Foreign Key 

}

public class EntityBilling
{
    //BillId -> Primary Key ->set automatically
    public int BillId { get; set; } 
    public int BillAmount { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string ModeOfPayment { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the picture of the ERD of the tables and Web Forms:
[image: ERD of One-to-One R]

[image: Enter Patient Diagnosis Web Form]

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand. But you can keep the information in your class object until the billing information is added. Once you have both, insert into Billing table first, that will give you BillId to be used as FK for diagnosis table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approach. You can change the relationship between entities PatientDiagnosis and Billing. So, at first you can create a PatientDiagnosis entry and then create a Billing entry for it.

```
public class EntityPatientDiagnosis
{
    //Diagnosis Id is automatically assigned   
    public int DiagnosisId { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string Symptoms { get; set; }
    public string DiagnosisProvided { get; set;}
    public string AdministeredBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateofDiagnosis { get; set; }
    public string FollowUpRequired { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfFollowUp { get; set; }

}


public class EntityBilling
{
    //BillId -> Primary Key ->set automatically
    public int BillId { get; set; }

    //DiagnosisId -> Foreign Key  unique
    public int DiagnosisId { get; set; }

    public int BillAmount { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string ModeOfPayment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Relationship between two entities depends upon their interaction and how they are defined in your system.
If in your system, a diagnosis has multiple billings, you should use one to many relation, if not, you can use one to one relation.

Comment: I also mentioned that in my post "Firstly, Because it has an extra update query....". But I don't want to do that because firstly my given project requirement had the Table Schema set up this way. Also I don't understand why does it work when you change up the relation . Because its one-to-one relation so as far as I know it shouldn't make any difference which table's primary key I am using to make the relation. Even-though it is making a clear difference here. I also want to know how does different online shops and other system/website does it.